# Showing an aggregated value based on the value of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, mdx

I have the following table structure

```
| ID | Date     | Value | IsForecast
| 1  | 1/1/2017 | $100  | 1
| 2  | 1/5/2017 | $50   | 0 
| 3  | 1/9/2017 | $30   | 0
| 4  | 2/1/2017 | $200  | 1
| 5  | 2/5/2017 | $120  | 0
| 6  | 2/8/2017 | $30   | 0
| 7  | 2/9/2017 | $60   | 0
| 8  | 3/1/2017 | $200  | 1
```

Note the Date column is actually a numerical value that keys off a Calendar table.

I want to basically create a view that shows the "Value" grouped by month, but if there is an Actual value (IsForecast = 0), then use the total of that value, but otherwise use the total if IsForecast = 1.

The result I'd like from the data above would be like this:

```
| Month | Value
| Jan   | $80     (Sum of IsForecast = 0)
| Feb   | $210    (Sum of IsForecast = 0)
| Mar   | $200    (Sum of IsForecast = 1, because there are no values where IsForecast = 0)
```

Essentially this is a Fact table, and Date keys off to a Time dimension, IsForecast keys off to a utility dimension to filter Actual Sales and Forecasts.

I have a requirement to show an aggregation that displays Sales and Forecasts in a single column, however if there is an actual sale value use that, and if not use the forecast.

I tried to do this in MDX `IIF((Measures.Value, [SalesMode].[Actual]) <> NULL, (Measures.Value, [SalesMode].[Actual]), (Measures.Value, [SalesMode].[Forecast]))` but this is playing hell with Grand Totals, because the total of the Sales+Forecasts column always shows the total sales value, rather than the total of the sales+forecasts. If anyone has an MDX suggestion then feel free, but I'm looking back to doing this in a SQL View and just pulling that through as a measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with something like this in a query that groups by month:

If all the rows within a month have isforecast=1, it sums all values.  Otherwise, it sums only the values where isforecast=0.

```
    case when min(isforecast) = 1 then sum(value)
         else sum(case when isforecast = 0 then value else 0 end)
    end
```

Comment: This errors, and I think it's because of the `MIN()` within the `SUM()`. - `Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.`

Comment: @JamesLove oops, have changed it.

Comment: Cheers, that seems to do what I'm after!